# Maya phone number query

Tags: python, maya

I'm working on a script that needs a phone number queried from an tex field or int field for maya. I using python and I can't seem to find anything that works. Can you help? 
Thanks
TED
Ok This is the mess that I came up with.

```
def makeTui():
    if(cmds.window('window2',q=1,ex=1)):cmds.deleteUI('window2')
    cmds.window('window2',menuBar=1)
    cmds.formLayout('formLayout1')
    cmds.text(label='Phone Number')
    num = cmds.intField('textField4',width=100,height=20,changeCommand = num_callback)
    cmds.text('text95',label='Service Provider')
    cmds.optionMenu('optionMenu1')
    cmds.menuItem(label='AT&T')
    cmds.menuItem(label='Verizon')
    cmds.menuItem(label='Sprint')
    cmds.menuItem(label='Cricket')
    cmds.menuItem(label='Tmobil')
    cmds.iconTextButton('iconTextButton45',parent='formLayout1',image='render.png',command='num_callback()')
    cmds.formLayout('formLayout1',e=1,attachForm=[['textField4', 'left', 100], ['text95', 'top', 30], ['optionMenu1', 'top', 30], ['optionMenu1', 'left', 100], ['iconTextButton45', 'left', 100], ['iconTextButton45', 'top', 60]])
    cmds.showWindow('window2')
makeTui()

def num_callback():
    print cmds.intField(num, q=True, value=True)
```

Comment: What have you already tried? What's the end goal? Adding more information and noting that you've already tried will definitely help get a good answer

Comment: I want the user to enter in their phone number and then a text message is sent after a batch render is finished. I have the rest of the code (not shown) I just need to add a valuable for the phone number.

Comment: it is better to use pyside widgets for such stuff on maya instead of the crappy cmds maya menus

Answer (score 0):

You want to define your callback function in the same scope as the UI items - that saves a lot of work in trying to remember the names of the widgets that you need to work on.

```
def create_ui():

    window = cmds.window()
    column  = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

    # three items arranged horizontally
    row = cmds.rowLayout(nc = 3)
    numfield = cmds.textFieldGrp(label = 'phone number')
    cmds.text("provider")
    provider = cmds.optionMenu()
    for p in ('AT&T', 'Verizon', 'Sprint', 'T-Mobile'):
        cmds.menuItem(label = p)
    cmds.setParent("..")

    # define this function here so it knows the widgets for 
    # the text field and the option menu
    def render_button():
        phoneno = cmds.textFieldGrp(numfield, q=True, text=True)
        # remove any punctuation:
        digits =[int(c) for c in phoneno if c.isdigit()]
        providername  = cmds.optionMenu(provider, q=True, v=True)
        print digits, providername


    cmds.iconTextButton(image='render.png', c = render_button)
    cmds.showWindow(window)
```

Here the callback function knows the 'names' of the field for entering numbers and the optionmenu for picking providers.  The actual work would go into the `render_buttons()` function.  I used a text field, incidentally, since many people will expect to type things like 1(555)111-2222 and an `intField` wont' allow it.